# Spring batch retry-limit

Tags: spring, spring-batch

When defining a spring batch job and using retry-limit parameter in xml description is it the total number of runs, or the number of retries?
i.e. when retry-limit=1, will my job run once or twice (in case of an error on the first run)?

This seems like a silly question, but I didn't find a clear answer in any documentation I've seen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `retry-limit` attribute is really "item-based" and not "job-based". By "item-based" I mean that for every item (record/line) that is read/processed/writen, if that item fails, it will be retried up the retry-limit. If that limit is reached, the *step* will fail.

For example

```
<step id="someStep">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"
               processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="20"
               retry-limit="3">
            <retryable-exception-classes>
                <include class="org.springframework.exception.SomeException"/>
            </retryable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

In the above basic step configuration, when a `SomeException` is thrown by any of the components in the step (`itemReader`, `itemWriter`, or `itemProcessor`), the item is retried up to three times before the step fails.

---

Here's Spring doc's explanation

> In most cases you want an exception to cause either a skip or Step failure. However, not all exceptions are deterministic. If a `FlatFileParseException` is encountered while reading, it will always be thrown for that record; resetting the `ItemReader` will not help. However, for other exceptions, such as a `DeadlockLoserDataAccessException`, which indicates that the current process has attempted to update a record that another process holds a lock on, waiting and trying again might result in success. In this case, retry should be configured:

```
<step id="step1">
   <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"
             commit-interval="2" retry-limit="3">
         <retryable-exception-classes>
            <include class="org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException"/>
         </retryable-exception-classes>
      </chunk>
   </tasklet>
</step>
```

> The Step allows a limit for the number of times an individual item can be retried, and a list of exceptions that are 'retryable'. More details on how retry works can be found in [**Chapter 9, Retry**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html).

Comment: That's all great, and I'm more or less familiar with it ;-)
I asked for something very specific...
I think the answer for my question is hidden in the second line of your text, right? :-)

Comment: What exactly is the question? I thought my answer covered the questions you asked.- 1) _"is it the total number of runs, or the number of retries?"_ -> it's the number of retried. 2) _" job run once or twice (in case of an error on the first run)"_ -> your job will run once, but has nothing to do with the retry limit. the retry limit is for the item processing, not job runs. Jobs and Items are two different concepts

Comment: Is it possible you're not asking the right question, if you're looking for a different answer?

Comment: Ok, then the "item" will run twice in this case, right?

Comment: Yes it will run twice. Once for the main run and second for the retry.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I got confused by your usage of "job", but replacing "item" with "job" your question makes more sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

spring batch job gets failed if any step fails to complete execution without any error or exception.
If any error or exception occurs in any steps the step is defined as failed, with this the job is also defined as failed job.

First of all, if you want to restart a job you need to make sure that the job is defined as restart-able. Otherwise 
you can not run the same job again. More over a job is restart-able only and only if it was failed in the previous 
attempt. Once it is finished successfully you can not restart a job even if it is declared as restart-able, Yes you can but the job parameter has to be have different.

the retry-limit attribute defines how many times a failed task/step of a failed job can be retry to start

To use retry-limit you also need to defined on which exception or error it should retry

Answer (score 0):

The retry-limit attribute is really "item-based" and not "job-based". By "item-based" I mean that for every item (record/line) that is read/processed/writen, if that item fails, it will be retried up the retry-limit. If that limit is reached, the step will fail.

For example if retry-limit is set as 2, it will try to execute for twice.