# retry in spring batch asyncprocessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are building a spring batch which calls an third party API in processor section in spring batch

The requirement is when the 3rd party API is not available the spring batch need to re-try for specified threshold limit and abort the batch

I have tried spring batch retry with fault tolerant step it is working fine in a single threaded program but is is not stopping the batch when we include aysncprocessor and aysncitemwriter

https://github.com/mminella/LearningSpringBatch/blob/master/src/asyncItemProcessorItemWriter/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/configuration/JobConfiguration.java

Can some please give me some example of retry limit / custom code on how to exit in case of any exception using aysncprocessor / asyncitemwriter

**Update 1-:**
I have tried with chunk size of 100 with 5 aysnc threads with retry limit 3, I see few records are processed only twice and few are processed thrice and finally job fails with `ExhaustedRetryException`

Is this the expected behavior of Spring batch ?

**Update 2:-**
I see many post in forums with spring retry what is the exact difference between spring retry and faultTolerant (Spring Batch) step retry ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266598/spring-batch-retry-limit

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai: This does not work in aysncprocessor :(

Comment: `it is working fine in a single threaded program but is is not stopping the batch when we include aysncprocessor and aysncitemwriter`: Since its working fine let's see why it is not stopping. Are you using a thread pool executor for async components? If yes, do you shutdown this thread pool after your job? Spring Batch does not shutdown thread pools by itself.

Comment: yes we are using task executor but we are not shutting it down , we though SpringApplication.exit(context) would take care

Comment: it is working fine in a single threaded program but is is not stopping the batch when we include aysncprocessor and aysncitemwriter: Here I meant to say even though exception is thrown the batch continues to process and processor does not exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retry is configurable for both `Sync` and `Async` but there is a difference**

- In oder to observe this, reduce the `chunk` size to 2
- When it is `Async`, it submits every item in the chunk (in this case 2 and lets say both items are throwing exception during processing), then it will retry these 2 items again, and it will do 3 (`retryLimit`) rounds.

```
    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .chunk(2)
                .reader(pagingItemReader())
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .faultTolerant().retryLimit(3)
                                .retry(YourException.class)
                .writer(asyncItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

**Summary:**

- When you use `synchronous` processor, items in the chunk are processed sequentially. So when one item fails, only that item is retried as per `retryLimit`
- When you use `asynchronous` processor, items in that chunk are processed in parallel. So when one or more items in that fails, all of them are retried 3 times as per `retryLimit`

Comment: I will check and update in some time thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: I have checked my chunk size is 100 with 5 threads some times I see that few records are processed only 2 times and the job failed with ExhaustedRetryException even though the retry limit is 3 worried to use this retry feature

Comment: In sync mode, maximum failures before batch realises and retrying is 1 record. But in async mode, it will process records in parallel. That means once it cannot stop other threads once one thread detects failure. So in your case, it will retry all dailed records. But it will wait until all threads have finished the current item in hand. I.e maximum of 5. It is still reliable as it will still retry

Comment: Hi ,I have been trying to research some records are processed four times, so my question is what happens if only one record fails in the chunk size of 100 will it fail the entire step ? Also not sure though the retry limit is 3 some records are processed 4 times really appreciate your help and guidance :)