# retry without rollback spring batch asyncprocessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

This question is a continuation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636652/retry-in-spring-batch-asyncprocessor) question

We are using [aysncProcessor and ayscItemWriter](https://github.com/mminella/LearningSpringBatch/blob/master/src/asyncItemProcessorItemWriter/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/configuration/JobConfiguration.java) as mentioned with 5 threads and chunk size of 100 in the processor we are calling an 3rd party API , we want to use the retry(retry limit 3) mechanism in case if the service is down and exit the batch . Could you please help me with the below questions

**Question 1 -:** - What will happen if one of the  item in the chunk fails (ex: 3 retries) and other 99 are successful will the batch still fail ?

**Question 2 -:** -: Currently I throw an custom exception if the 3rd party service is down, I want to store the all items of chunk in db before spring batch terminates , so that we will have which records has succeeded , which one failed . Currently spring batch terminates from processor and writer is never called .